# How do I search a string in powershell and delete the line?

Tags: python, shell, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

If i have 5 words in a text file

---

```
red car

yellow flower

purple heart

vault of grass

hard light
```

How do I search for the word then delete it and save/overwrite...its easy in python but powershell is a little complicated for me with this.

### So far this is what i have

```
#name new file
$fileName = read-host "Enter fileName: "

#create new text file to save processes
$textFile = New-Item  C:\Users\socrateslouis\Documents\$folderName\$fileName".txt" -type file

#store in text file
$outfile =Get-Process | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\socrates\Documents\$folderName\$fileName".txt"
#display processes

$processFile = Get-Content C:\Users\socrates\Documents\$folderName\$fileName".txt"

$processFile
```

Comment: what has this got to do with python?

Comment: Show us your code in Python, then

Comment: From what i can see you are outputting a list of processes to a text file. So are you saying you have a process named 'red car' in the output file and want to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$File = 'TestFile.txt'
$tempFile = 'TestFileTmp.txt'
$stringToMatch = "vault"

Get-Content $File | Where { $_ -notmatch $stringToMatch } | Set-Content $tempFile
Remove-Item -Path $File
Rename-Item -Path $tempFile -NewName $File -Force
```